# Meiotic recombination hotspots

Tags: human-biology, database, meiosis, recombination

Im trying to find a proper and general file with chromosomal coordinates for meiotic recombination hotspots.

I know that ucsc hgtables, has a table with recombination regions and their recombination rate. However these regions are all 1Mb, and several articles states that these hotspots regions are more local with a regional length of 2Kb.

https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTables?hgsid=782680683_Cxp9zzjwgsql7P0T81FFyATyTNOl&clade=mammal&org=&db=hg19&hgta_group=map&hgta_track=recombRate&hgta_table=recombRate&hgta_regionType=range&position=&hgta_outputType=primaryTable&hgta_outFileName=

Do any of you know of a file or database containing the chromosome coordinates for humans which have been identified as a recombination hotspots?

Thanks a lot for your time and help.